# ImageMagick read PDF causes Apache crash

Tags: apache, imagick

My Apache server is crashing when I'm trying to read PDF.

```
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImage('file.pdf');
```

**There is no issue when I do something with images file, so the extension works.**
Only PDF files are problematic.

Can some one give me an idea what to do with it??

[Apache crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQJXl.png)

```
Using:

Apache: 2.4.7
MySQL: 5.6.15
PHP: 5.6.14 (memory_limit = 1024M)
php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86
ImageMagick-6.8.8-7-Q16-x86-dll

WinServer 2012r2 x64
```

[Imagick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IaJH.png)

Apache crash text:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX (Buffer Overflow Exception)
  Application Name: eds-httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.7.0
  Application Timestamp:    528e59ed
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR100.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.40219.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4d5f0c22
  Exception Offset: 0008af3e
  Exception Code:   c0000417
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 4756
  Additional Information 2: 4756014c9a5ad7cbbe391ea987d65a18
  Additional Information 3: 3b30
  Additional Information 4: 3b3003002d9736fb7e4bf7c51fe7a0dc
```

And when I try to add eds-httpd.exe to "DEP" exceptions list,
It says "This program MUST run with 'DEP' enabled"

Comment: Does this happen when you run the script from the command line? And can you generate a stacktrace from whatever tool does that in windows.

Comment: Works fine with command line.

Comment: @It_Never_Works I am experiencing the same issue. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: No :(  i just stopped using ImageMagick.